# How to cast controller to a specific protocol instead of a class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, segue

This is my `protocol`:

```
protocol DBViewAnimationTransitioning {
    var viewForAnimation: UIView? { get set }
}
```

Example of usage inside `prepareForSegue:`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? DBViewAnimationTransitioning {
        controller.viewForAnimation = sender as? UIView //cannot assign to to viewForAnimation in controller
    }
}
```

Everything is fine when I cast to specific controller f.e. `DBFindViewController`. But I need to cast this to the specific `protocol` not `class`. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can only check for protocol conformance (which includes `is`, `as`, and `as?`) with an `@objc protocol`.

So the solution is simple:

```
@objc protocol DBViewAnimationTransitioning {
    var viewForAnimation: UIView? { get set }
}
```

or:

```
protocol DBViewAnimationTransitioning: class {
    var viewForAnimation: UIView? { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the protocol isn't specifically for a class/struct it cannot assign something because it may be a struct which would make no sense because it is copied. Try making it a class protocol by declaring it like `protocol DBViewAnimationTransitioning : class`